# Index out of bounds error during image passing

Tags: c#, dictionary, exception, bitmap, resources

So I am coding a small program that takes a users input ie their name and compares what they type to a list of bitmap images that represent the alphabet and are named accordingly ie "A.bmp","B.bmp" and so on. To do the comparison I decided to use a Data Dictionary to hold the image's name and the image itself so that when it found a match to the character of the string it sends the relevant image back to be stored in an bitmap array.

However when i run my "Process" class that does the comparison I get an Index out of bounds exception even though i have my 2 for loops set to stop when they reach the end of their respective data arrays.

I get the error on this line:

```
pics.Add(namesAndImages[namesAndImages.Keys.ElementAt(i)]);
```

I have all the images referenced in the solution resources so i dont know if its not actually adding them using the resource manager or if ive missed something.

This is my code for my process class

```
private void Process()
{
    fullName = lblFirst.Text.ToString() + lblLast.Text.ToString();

    var nameString = fullName.ToCharArray();
    List<System.Drawing.Bitmap> pics = new List<Bitmap>();

    Boolean converted = false;
    int i, x;

    var namesAndImages = new Dictionary<String, Bitmap>();

    var resourcesSet = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, true, true);

    foreach (System.Collections.DictionaryEntry myResource in resourcesSet)
    {
        if (myResource.Value is Bitmap) //is this resource is associated with an image
        {
            String resName = myResource.Key.ToString(); //get resource's name
            Bitmap resImage = myResource.Value as Bitmap; //get the Image itself

            namesAndImages.Add(resName, resImage);
        }
    }

    while (converted == false)
    {
        for (x = 0; x <= nameString.Length; x++)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < namesAndImages.Count; i++)
            {
                if (nameString[x].Equals(namesAndImages.Keys.ElementAt(i)))
                {
                    pics.Add(namesAndImages[namesAndImages.Keys.ElementAt(i)]);
                }
            }
        }
        converted = true;

    }
    String[] imageData = new String[pics.Count];

    for (int y = 0; y <= pics.Count; y++)
    {
        imageData[y] = ConvertImage(pics[y]);
    }

    output = CombineBitmap(imageData);

}
```

the combine bitmap class is one that i found that stitches multiple bitmaps together into one single bitmap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing this is the line that causes the exception :

```
for (x = 0; x <= nameString.Length; x++)
```

it should be

```
for (x = 0; x < nameString.Length; x++)
```

You are trying to access one character beyond the length of the string.

Similarly here :

```
for (int y = 0; y <= pics.Count; y++)
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
for (x = 0; x <= nameString.Length; x++)
```

to

```
for (x = 0; x < nameString.Length; x++)
```

and

```
 for (int y = 0; y <= pics.Count; y++)
```

to

```
 for (int y = 0; y < pics.Count; y++)
```

Comment: Thank you Pablo and Paul that seems to have fixed that particular issue but I am now getting another issue that I will post below if yous could have a look at it for me as well please.

Comment: @MacMan   You should mark the answers as correct & accept one. If your question is about another problem - then you should probably start a new question as this one will be considered answered.